# Triggering GitLab push events on multiple branches

Tags: gitlab, hook, push, continuous-delivery

How can I set two or more branches to trigger the hook? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUJ64.png)

For example:
I have three branches: master; develop and fix.
I want the hook to work for master and develop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[gitlab-org/gitlab-foss issue 20338](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/20338) which introduced "filter push events by branch" in GitLab 11.3 (Sept. 2018) includes:

> support for branch patterns with wildcards (`*`), like we do [with protected branches](https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/protected_branches#wildcard-protected-branches).

So the pattern itself is fairly limited:

```
| Wildcard Protected Branch | Matching Branches                                |
|===========================|==================================================|
| *-stable                  | production-stable, staging-stable                |
| production/*              | production/app-server, production/load-balancer  |
| *gitlab*                  | gitlab, gitlab/staging, master/gitlab/production |
```

There is no `xxx|yyy` or syntax.

In your case, the pattern `*e*` would be enough to select only `master` and `develop`, *not* `fix`.

Comment: I don't think so, bcs if I create a branch with e letter, it will trigger hook too. But I can add one hook to master branch and second hook to develop branch :)

Comment: @AndreyRF I agree, that was a workaround indeed. Your solution is safer, even if it involves more hooks.